# botocore and urllib3 conflicting dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I need some help with this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 7) and urllib3==1.26.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested urllib3==1.26.5
    botocore 1.13.50 depends on urllib3<1.26 and >=1.20; python_version >= "3.4"

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

It says about an incompatibility between botocore and urllib3, but not sure what version is needed.

Comment: From where is the requirements.txt file? I see 2 options:
1.) downgrade urllib3 to 1.25 
2.) omit botocore from the requirements list